# probability density functions and cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is an absolutely continuous real random variable, (that is, there exist a non-negative integrable function $f$, such that $\int_\mathbb{R} f=1$ and for every interval $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\int_I f = P(X \in I)$, such $f$ is called a density function of $X$) and let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function.

I was told that the density function of $X$ is never completely determined, because if $f$ is a density function of $X$, changing its values on a finite set you still get a density function of $X$.
But I know that where $F$ is differentiable, $F'(x)=f(x)$ for every density function $f$.
I was thinking that if $F$ is differentiable everywhere, then there should be an only density function. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability density function is defined for a specific measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (usually, the Lebesgue measure), and the integrals $\int_\mathbb{R} f$ and $\int_{I}f$ should be written as $\int_\mathbb{R} f d \mu$ and $\int_I f d\mu$. The probability density function is defined $\mu$-[almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) uniquely (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Discussion), as it is, strictly speaking, the Radon–Nikodym derivative $\frac{d P}{d \mu}$ of the probability measure $P$ w.r.t. $\mu$. However, in case of Lebesgue measure $\mu$ $F'(x)$ is one of those $\mu$-a.e. probability density functions.

Edit: essentially, a probability density function on a real line is not unique. The wrong equation is $F'(x) = f(x)$, the correct version of which is $\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt = F(x)$ for any real $x$ (and where Lebesgue, not Riemann integration is used).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a first year math student, and our probability course doesn't use measure. Is it possible to give a more elementary explanation?

Comment: @AngeloRusso, I added a simplified explanation.

Comment: I think you mean $\int_{-\infty}  ^x f(t)dt = F(x)$ for all real $x$. So we can't differentiate both sides (we don't know that $f$ is continuous, I got confused at this point). Just a last question: why do you say that lebesgue integral is used? Isn't it the usual improper integral? Thanks!

Comment: @AngeloRusso, yes, you are right about the formula. The result of differentiation is not unique, because $f$ can be changed in a countable amount of points and the integral's value will not change. (However, for real line [Lusin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) states that the result of differentiation will be "nearly continuous".) Lebesgue integral is used because it allows a wider class of distributions and sample spaces, but for real line if improper Riemann integral converges absolutely, then the corresponding Lebesgue integral has the same value.

Answer (score 0):

An elementary example can be found by using a uniformly-distributed random variable with positive probability on [0,1] versus the uniform distribution with support (0,1). Both RV`s have the same CDF (they`re equal at every point), but different densities (as a result of the behaviour at the endpoints).

Comment: This might be nitpicking, but [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28measure_theory%29) is often defined to be closed, so in your example both variables can have the same support, depending on exact definition.

Comment: In it is arguable the distribution or a real-valued random variable is fully expressed by the cumulative distribution function, so these two examples have the same distribution and so the same support.